# KeyUpHandler firing only once

Tags: gwt, keyboard-events

I'm trying to make a KeyUpHandler work (popup the value of the TextBox) for a TextBox widget. In the simple implementation below it only fires once and then it throws an error in the firefox console:

```
uncaught exception: java.lang.AssertionError: Negative entryDepth value at exit -1
```

I use run as superdev mode in eclipse Luna.
There is no errors at compile time.

```
//imports
public class myClass implements EntryPoint {
    private VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
    private TextBox box = new TextBox();

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        panel.add(box);
        RootPanel.get("gwtContainer").add(panel);
        box.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
                Window.alert(box.getValue());
            }
         });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 final TextBox box = new TextBox();
 ...
 box.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
            Window.alert(box.getValue());
        }
 });
```

Comment: sadly no, it desn't help. Sometimes it fires 2 or 3 times before throwing the exception.

Comment: I just tried to deploy the app to tomcat with GWT compile and it does work as expected... Any idea why the difference?

Comment: Maybe this one: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7926

Comment: Okay, I tried the superdev mode with Chromium instead and it works as expected. It looks like a bug with firefox (iceweasel). Thanks for pointing this out.